# Can we move any object in android with thread

Tags: android, android-layout

like is my code but this is having error of depreciated method of threads

```
class x implements Threads{
public void run()
{
 someButton.layout(10,k,40,40);

 k+=10;
}}
```

Comment: its Really `implements Thread ?`

Comment: could be possible only if he has class named `Threads`

Comment: @Areeb: Need to show the error.

Comment: i think OP creates `interface named Threads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can but that reason you have to use user interface thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // do your stuff here
                        }
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't You try Inbuilt Animations in Android

If you all wanted is to move object use `TranslateAnimation`

Don't forget to put `object.setFillAfter(true);`

Otherwise object will again come back to original place.

Below Snippet will help you.

```
package org.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AnimationActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Animation");

        final TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0,
                200, 0, 0);
        moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
        moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setText("PressMe");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                tv.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
            }

        });

        ll.addView(tv);
        ll.addView(button);
        setContentView(ll);

    }
}
```